# How to disable Magento crontab job

Tags: magento-1, cron

I'm trying to disable a cron job that's scheduled in a Core file (for reasons), but I haven't been able to find any information about that on the manual or the Internet.

I found that the job I want to disable will leave under `config > crontab> jobs > job_key` config node, I was planning to overwrite the `schedule > cron_expr` within that node and set its value to `null` in my module.

Anyone with any experience in doing this? Any alternative solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a recommended method or not, but it seems to work for me.  You can create your own extension for the purpose of overriding cron and adjust the settings in the *config.xml*.  To disable a core job, simply enter an empty *cron_expr* node.

For instance, We don't use the stock newsletter functionality in our store, so I wanted to disable the **newsletter_send_all** job.  To do this I put the following in my *config.xml*:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <newsletter_send_all>
            <schedule><cron_expr></cron_expr></schedule>
        </newsletter_send_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

As I said, this seems to work well, but I'd welcome any feedback if someone thinks this is a bad idea for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Cron jobs are scheduled through observers. The simplest way to disable one, is to rewrite the observer it is calling and reimplement the method to do nothing.

Future maintainers of your code will appreciate obvious naming and comments.

This has the additional advantage that you can implement your own toggle button in the backend. Your method will look something like this:

```
public function cronJobDoStuff($observer) {
    if( Mage::helper('my/module')->getEnableCronJobDoStuff() ) {
        return parent::cronJobDoStuff($observer);
    } else {
       return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: posted that your solution made sense before but, while implementing it, I realized that I would like to avoid that task being scheduled at all; i.e. calling a `doNothing` method is fine, but why should we call it in the first place? I'll keep investigating. Thanks!

Comment: Preventing the task being scheduled, means you need to modify the code of the extension / core, if it doesn't provide a means to disable it. All code in the core, provides a way to disable a job via the backend as far as I know (maybe not the Email sending in 1.9.1), but not all extensions do this. You have to weigh "fully optimized" versus "maintainability" and this is something only you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably replace the run > model node with your own method that does nothing:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <system_backup>
            <run>
                <model>my_module/observer::doNothing</model>
            </run>
        </system_backup>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: This worked for me EE 1.14.1.0 cheers, just make sure the module configuration you put them in depends on the module you are disabling.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this module... [Aoe/Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) We are using it and it is great for this kind of staff. Otherwise you have under *`System->Configuration->System->Cron (Scheduled Tasks) - all the times are in minutes->Disabled`* cron tasks... There you can provide crons that you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of @BrianVPS. Instead of leaving it empty, I propose to schedule it for "Feb 30", which will never occur.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <newsletter_send_all>
            <schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
        </newsletter_send_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Haven't tested, but should work.