# Turning off custom cron job

Tags: magento2, php, cron

I tried to create custom cron job and it's all works, but how can I turn it off so it will not run again.

I already tried to comment `(//)` the cron job in `crontab.xml` but it's not working.

Comment: Did you use // in an xml file instead of <!-- --> ?

Comment: ah yes i mean <!-- -->

Comment: OK - here is a post that may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62066/how-to-disable-magento-crontab-job

Comment: it's related to magento 1 but the bit about having a toggle is a good idea. this would be set in the code that is executed by the cron.  Otherwise someone else can perhaps assist in resetting the cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the cache and to prevent already scheduled tasks, clear the cron_schedule table (or specifically remove all rows with the tag of your custom cron job.)

Comment: So removing all rows with my custom cron job tag will stop the cron from scheduling?

Comment: @EdwinWidhiyanto No, removing the tasks from the cron_scehedule prevents tasks that are already sceduled from being executed. Commenting out the job in the crontab.xml and clearing the cache should prevent it from being added to the cron_schedule again.